# Predict with gls

Tags: r, predict, nlme

I'm learning how to predict with gls but I keep getting an error when I try to do that. Here's the code I'm using.

```
data("airquality")
airquality$Date=as.Date(paste(1973,airquality$Month,airquality$Day,sep="-"))
air1<-subset(airquality,complete.cases(Ozone))
library(nlme)
model1=gls(Ozone~Wind*Date,air1,correlation=corAR1())
```

This works fine so far. Now, I would like to predict the Ozone for a specific Wind Speed on a specific Date. So I use.

```
newdata<-data.frame(Wind=10,Date="1973-05-04")
newdata$Date<-as.Date(newdata$Date)
predict(model1,newdata)
```

The last code line gives me the following error:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Ozone' not found

I then tried the following code to predict:

```
predict.gls(model1,newdata)
```

This is the error I'm getting although the `nlme` library was included.

> Error: could not find function "predict.gls"

Can anyone advise why these errors are coming up? Also, what would be the right way code to use here to make the prediction?

Comment: what is `Date` in the `gls` call ? How did you defined it ?

Comment: I just added that line of code I used. It's the second line now.

Comment: I haven't got the error. it returns 35.37236. Are all of your packages up-to-date ?

Comment: Ya, I had just installed them. I tried restarting RStudio and now the first generic predict works but I get the same error as above when using the predict.gls function. Any idea why?

Comment: For the `predict.gls` error I don't know, it's the same for me. But as `predict` works I guess you don't need to use the `.gls` extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching the topic further, I realized that predict.gls is not a function in itself but rather used in the help files to identify and explain the arguments necessary to pass along with a gls object to the predict function.